# CDN files not Created in temp/deploy when shipping

Tags: spfx, script, modern, editor

1. I created modern script editor web part using this :
   https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor
2. Enabled CDN using SharePoint Power Management Shell
   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-cdn-in-your-office-365-tenant-for-spfx-webpart/
3. Created CDN folder also in Document library

But when I run command `gulp --ship` cdn files are not created.

What am I missing?.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but I think it will assist you in moving forward. In the project you linked, the `includeClientSideAssets` setting in **package-solution.json** is set to `true`. This means that you do not need to explicitly deploy the bundle files (static assets) to the Office 365 CDN. The bundle files will be included in the app package (the **.sppkg** file) and will automatically be added to the CDN when the package is deployed to the app catalog.

[image: Screen capture of package-solution.json]

As to your actual question, I'm not sure why the bundle files were not output to the **temp/deploy** folder. I haven't looked into this so I can only make an educated guess. My guess is that you need to take two steps to make this happen. First, set `includeClientSideAssets` setting in **package-solution.json** to `false`. Second, set the `cdnBasePath` property in **write-manifests.json** to the URL to the folder you created in the CDN.

[image: Screen capture of write-manifests.json]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I may have found the reason why bundle files were not output to the **temp/deploy** folder. The default location for resources used in deployments changed from **temp/deploy** to **releases/assets** in the SharePoint Framework v1.12.1.  Are you using SPFx v1.12.1 or later?

Comment: yes I am using SPFX v14.18.0 that's why I am facing these issues,webpart is working on hosted workbench but not taking any code which I am writing in text area like I wrote simple <script> console.log("hello");</script>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I did the same as per you suggestion:

[image: I did the same as per you suggestion]

Specified CDN path as well:

[image: Specified CDN path as well]

My temp folder has these files .I am sorry If I did any silly mistake as I am new to this, learning everyday

[image: My temp folder has these files .I am sorry If I did any silly mistake as I am new to this, learning everyday]